# MVVM Light and SQL Server CE generated code in viewmodel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, mvvm-light

I'm just having a play with MVVM Light and I think I got my head around it but I have a problem.

I'm using the SQL Server CE Toolbox which generates the classes, mappings etc for my database (SQLCE). One of the table's is called Profile and I wanted to use this as property that I can bind too. Here is my code for the ViewModel

```
public class ProfileViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Profile profile; // Profile is the class created by SQLCE Toolbox for table mapping

    public Profile UserProfile 
    {
        get { return profile; }
        set
        {
            profile = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("UserProfile");
        }
    }

    public ProfileViewModel()
    {  
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
            UserProfile = new Profile()
            {
               Name = "NA",
               Age = 22
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Code runs "for real"
            UserProfile = GetProfile(); 
        }
    }
}
```

In Expression blend I can see the ViewModel but not the Profile property so I'm guessing an exception is being generated somewhere.

I did try attaching blend as a process but no errors came up. After a little reading and I see that blend can't connect to the database so you have to make up some data when in DesignMode. I tried just doing `UserProfile = new Profile()` but I am guessing it is still trying to use the database to create it?

EDIT:
Ok the issue I am having I think is related to using SQLCE. If I try something similar with WPF and MS SQL then everything works fine.

EDIT 2:
This is deffinatly related to the database. If I remove the public property UserProfile from the code above then all the other properties (not shown in my code) can be seen from Blend. If I add it back then none are visable. So how can I make it blendable?

Comment: Just a note. If you're assigning `profile` in the constructor, you don't have to assign it in the field declarations.

Comment: Yeah your right that was a "clutching at straws" attempt without thinking

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `Locator` mechanism. You can see it by default in a MVVM application.

When in design mode, you will provide a pre-built version of your `Profile` object, but when in the non-design mode the `Profile` object will be given through your database. So you won't use `new Profile()` directly but something along the lines of `Locator.ProvideMeWithUserProfile()`.

You can have a look at [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/EX14) for example for a way to achieve it.

Comment: I saw his other video which looks similar but I will take a closer look

Comment: please mark as an answer to close the thread if it answers your concern.

Comment: So how do you create the pre-built version? the class profile has 2 properties called Name and Age. Are you saying that pre-built is when I do profile = new Profile() { Name = "NA"; Age = 30; }?

Answer (score 1):

I notice a couple things here.

You're assigning your design-time data (and non-design time) to the backing field, and not the property, so your RaisePropertyChanged() isn't being called. This would keep the view from updating if the property changes, but you should still "have access" to the property. May not be a problem since this is happening in the constructor.

Also, in your text you keep talking about the Profile property, but the property is really called UserProfile.